# Android findViewById() with onFling in ListView problem

Tags: android, listview, gesture-recognition

I have a class that extend ListActivity.
This class show a AbsListView filled with bus IDs and a bus Names on each row...
I try to handle the bus Name of a row when I make a swipe gesture on...('onFling') but when I do that, the gesture is handled correctly but I can just get the Views (with findViewByID()) of the first row ....I need to get the  Views of the Flinged row!

Thank you!

This is my code...:

```
public class dayBusList extends ListActivity{

     AbsListView lv;
 AABDatabaseManager db;

     GestureDetector mGestureDetector = null;
 View.OnTouchListener mGestureListener = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        db = new AABDatabaseManager(dayBusList.this);
        setListAdapter(new SpeechListAdapter(this));



        lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
        lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        lv.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);

        //Gesture detector for swipe...

         mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());

             mGestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent aEvent) {

                    if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(aEvent))
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                    }
                };
       lv.setOnTouchListener(mGestureListener);
```

.......>THE ADAPTER FOR THE LIST VIEW

```
private class SpeechListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

         private Context mContext;
         private String[] busIDS = db.getDayBusIds();
         private String[] busNAMES = db.getDayBusNames();

            public SpeechListAdapter(Context context) {

                mContext = context;
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return busNAMES.length;
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                SpeechView sv;

                if (convertView == null) {
                    sv = new SpeechView(mContext, busIDS[position],
                            busNAMES[position]);
                } else {
                    sv = (SpeechView) convertView;
                    sv.setTitle(busIDS[position]);
                    sv.setDialogue(busNAMES[position]);
                }
                return sv;
            }

         }

        private class SpeechView extends LinearLayout {

            private TextView busID;
            private TextView busNAME;

            public SpeechView(Context context, String title, String words) {
                super(context);

                this.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

                ImageView busIcon = new ImageView(context);
                busIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.stm);
                busIcon.setPadding(2, 20, 5, 20);
                addView(busIcon,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                busID = new TextView(context);
                busID.setId(1);
                busID.setTextSize(30);
                busID.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                busID.setPadding(5, 15, 5, 20);
                //busID.setPadding(0, 0,10, 0);
                busID.setText(title);
                addView(busID, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                busNAME = new TextView(context);
                busNAME.setId(2);
                busNAME.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
                busNAME.setTextSize(15);
                busNAME.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                busNAME.setText(words);
                busNAME.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                busNAME.setWidth(160);
                addView(busNAME, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             }

            public void setTitle(String id) {
                busID.setText(id);
            }

            public void setDialogue(String name) {
                busNAME.setText(name);
            }
        }
```

.......>THE class for the gesture detection

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 200;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;

    @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                float dX = e2.getX()-e1.getX();
                float dY = e1.getY()-e2.getY();
                if (Math.abs(dY)<SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH &&
                    Math.abs(velocityX)>=SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY &&
                    Math.abs(dX)>=SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE ) {
                    if (dX>0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) findViewById(1)).getText()+"Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) findViewById(1)).getText()+"Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    return true;
                } 
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to override/implement the onTouchEvent() of your SpeechView class and handle the swipe within the SpeechView instance itself. You can then examine the properties of the SpeechView instance to know which row was swiped.

```
public class SpeechView extends LinearLayout
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        // 1) process any specific SpeecView instance variables.
        // 2) pass event to a gestureDetector.
        return true;
    }

}
```

Additionally, you can pass a GestureDetector into your SpeechListAdapter and feed the to the SpeechView class when it is originally created. Then you can pass the MotionEvents into it.

In either case, be sure to intercept the touch event by returning *true*.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)
{
    m_gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just happen to be lucky that `findViewById(1))` is actually defined. You shouldn't call findViweById in your gesture detector. I'm surprised that doesn't crash.

Instead, you get the view back in your onGestureListener. Use it there.